# Incorrect syntax using vb.net when there are no values in integer cells in datagridview?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have an update query which takes values from the datagridview in vb.net and updates the table in the database.

While executing the update statement its obvious that some fields in datagridview will not be filled due to some conditions.when i am executing the update statement it gives the error as incorrect syntax near ','. heres the query which i got.

```
updatestring = "update  pos_lti_dtl set item_code='" & X.Cells(4).Value & "',
description='" & X.Cells(5).Value & "',pack_sent=" & X.Cells(0).Value & ",
pack_received=" & X.Cells(2).Value & ",batch='" & X.Cells(6).Value & "',
expiry_date='" & X.Cells(7).Value & "',LOOSE_sent=" & X.Cells(2).Value & ",
LOOSE_received=" & X.Cells(3).Value & " where lti_no='" & transferno & "'"
```

i did some debugging and found out the following in the updatestring here it is

```
update  pos_lti_dtl set item_code='IIII',
description='',pack_sent=12,pack_received=,
batch='KKKKK',expiry_date='1/1/1900',
LOOSE_sent=,LOOSE_received= where lti_no='LTI/11011/2013'
```

well i have some numeric fields which can have no values at times and also i have enclosed the numeric values in "" as its the norm and when those fields dont have valuesit gives such errors,kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using it as a string only will cause a whole lot of problems for you. If you want to have a near 100% success rate, use sql variables.

```
    Dim ConString As String = "your connection"
    Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim sSQL = "UPDATE pos_lti_dtl SET "

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(4).Value
    sSQL += "item_code = @item_code, "
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(5).Value
    sSQL += "description=@description,"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pack_sent", SqlDbType.Int).Value = x.Cells(0).Value
    sSQL += "pack_sent=@pack_sent, "
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pack_received", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(2).Value
    sSQL += "pack_received=@pack_received, "
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@batch", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(6).Value
    sSQL += "batch=@batch, "
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@expiry_date", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(7).Value
    sSQL += "expiry_date=@expiry_date, "
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOOSE_sent", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(2).Value
    sSQL += "LOOSE_sent=LOOSE_sent@, "
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOOSE_received", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(3).Value
    sSQL += "LOOSE_received=@LOOSE_received "
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lti_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = transferno
    sSQL += "WHERE lti_no=@lti_no"
```

To break the above code down, What i do is i initialize my command string `sSQL` then i build more onto it as i add more sql variables `cmd.Parameters.Add`.
I add the `item_code` by first adding it as an sql variable. I called this variable `@item_code` and declared it as an integer ´SqlDbType.Int´ and assigned the value of ´X.Cells(4).Value´

> cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = X.Cells(4).Value

Next i added it to the sSQL

> sSQL += "item_code = @item_code, "

I added some spaces for easier overview of the string if something is bothering for easier debugging.

This will ensure that if the values is empty it will still run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You must write it like this

```
updatestring = "update  pos_lti_dtl set item_code='" & X.Cells(4).Value & "',
description='" & X.Cells(5).Value & "',pack_sent='" & X.Cells(0).Value & "',
pack_received=" & X.Cells(2).Value & ",
batch='" & X.Cells(6).Value & "',
expiry_date='" & X.Cells(7).Value & "',
LOOSE_sent='" & X.Cells(2).Value & "',
LOOSE_received='" & X.Cells(3).Value & "' where lti_no='" & transferno & "'"
```

So in execution it would look like this

```
update  pos_lti_dtl set item_code='IIII',
description='',pack_sent='12',pack_received='',
batch='KKKKK',expiry_date='1/1/1900',
LOOSE_sent='',LOOSE_received='' where lti_no='LTI/11011/2013'
```

You cannot have `columnname=` and then nothing, it must be enclosed with `'`.

This `LOOSE_sent=,` fails

This `LOOSE_sent='',` will work

This `LOOSE_sent=1,` will work but if no integer value is passed it will fail.

EDIT

If the fields `LOOSE_sent` and `LOOSE_received` are empty, then they must be taken out of the query **if they are of datatype** `integer` in the database. Like this

```
updatestring = "update  pos_lti_dtl set item_code='" & X.Cells(4).Value & "',
description='" & X.Cells(5).Value & "',pack_sent='" & X.Cells(0).Value & "',
pack_received=" & X.Cells(2).Value & ",
batch='" & X.Cells(6).Value & "',
expiry_date='" & X.Cells(7).Value & "'
where lti_no='" & transferno & "'"
```

Comment: the query you have posted is the one which gets created when it starts executing..my original query is this updatestring = "update  pos_lti_dtl set item_code='" & X.Cells(4).Value & "',description='" & X.Cells(5).Value & "',pack_sent=" & X.Cells(0).Value & ",pack_received=" & X.Cells(2).Value & ",batch='" & X.Cells(6).Value & "',expiry_date='" & X.Cells(7).Value & "',LOOSE_sent=" & X.Cells(2).Value & ",LOOSE_received=" & X.Cells(3).Value & " where lti_no='" & transferno & "'"

Comment: and i have enclosed it "" as its numeric and not string

Comment: Even if it is numeric doesnt mather. If there is no integer value then it will fail. You should always enclose every column with '

Comment: so u meant to say like this loose_sent ='"& X.Cells(2).Value &"',even if the table field in database is numeric.will it work

Comment: If the field is integer it wont be able to save since the value is not integer. But then you must take the loose_sent= out of the update query if it doest have a value. The SQL SYNTAX needs to have the column enclosed with ' unless a integer values is passed. If no integer value is passed then you must take out the column from the update syntax or it wont be able to update your query as its trying to set a integer field to ''